# Combine Multiple Search & Replace Expressions into One in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have to clean a couple of .txt files which are containing various URLs.
 I use Notepad++ search and replace function to remove these from the URLs:

- https://
- http://
- www.
- /[[:space:]]*$
- convert all to lowercase

I do this by replacing each item one after the other and I wonder if there is a way to combine at least some of these together.

Comment: Have you considered using the macro functionality to record, save and playback a macro with your desired actions?

Comment: Yes, I have but I was wondering if there was another way of doing it.

Comment: Writing a script (using Bash or Powershell) would be another way.